# Where can I find file on Android (DDMS)

Tags: android

I try to write string to file in my class, extends AsyncTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            DataOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new DataOutputStream(openFileOutput("1xdf.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                try {
                    out.writeUTF(Integer.toString(i));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                out.close();
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "6x");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Where can I finde this file in DDMs? When I try search->file 1xdf.xml, I get

> Problems encountered during text search. File
>   'MainActivity/bin/jarlist.cache' has been skipped, problem while
>   reading: ('Resource is out of sync with the file system:
>   '/MainActivity/bin/jarlist.cache'.'). Resource is out of sync with the
>   file system: '/MainActivity/bin/jarlist.cache'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DDMS perspective in Eclipse, select the 'File Explorer' tab and then open the following path:

```
data/data/com.your.package.name.here/files/1xdf.xml
```

Where 'com.your.package.name.here' is the name of your project's package / application name. If you want to move the file to your file system, select the 'Pull a file from the device' button on the top right (looks like a floppy disk with a pink arrow pointing to the left) and select the directory on your computer where you want to save the file.

If you want to manually load a file onto your virtual device, use the button to the right of the one above (that looks like a right facing arrow pointing to a phone).

Comment: When I try to Pull a file from device I geting error 
[2012-12-12 08:48:42] Failed to pull selection
[2012-12-12 08:48:42] null

Comment: i didn't find files in my data, only cache and lib options are there.can u tell me how can i view my saved file

Comment: Are you writing out the file correctly (DataOutputStream or similar)?  Make sure you are also catching any exceptions that may be occurring.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `context.openFileOutput()`, the files are written into the app's data. To check what this path is, you can call `getFilesDir()`.